# Build PySpark docker image minikube

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, minikube

I have minikube spark setup created with Helm Chart (spark-7.0.1, spark 3.4.0)- 1 master, 3 workers on 1 node. I also have my python script listed on public repo: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/michalpicheta/pythondbconnector/general

I am trying to launch python srcript within worker (and than master) pod.
So I used commands listed in documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html that are:

```
$ ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my-tag -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

but every time I run this as:

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r docker.io/michalpicheta/pythondbconnector  -t python  -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

or this:

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r docker.io/michalpicheta/pythondbconnector  -t python build
```

it shows an Error:

> ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh: line 177: docker: command not found Failed
> to build Spark JVM Docker image, please refer to Docker build output
> for details.

What am I doing wrong?
Is it because I did not provide more nodes?
Documentation says:

> Be aware that the default minikube configuration is not enough for
> running Spark applications. We recommend 3 CPUs and 4g of memory to be
> able to start a simple Spark application with a single executor.